# Using sync command upon startup

Tags: linux, filesystems, boot, synchronization

I'm using linux 4.1.8 32bit (yocto env) on an PPC embedded system.

On each startup the init process (systemV init) performs mount to a 15GB ext4 fs (nand flash).

Later (still by the init process and before getty invocation) the sync command is being executed.

Sometimes it hangs (takes about 20 sec) and sometimes not (run smoothly).

1. What is the reason for using the sync command upon system's **startup**? (even before a login is made).
2. Can I safely remove the sync call upon startup? (I would like to do that in order for the system to always boot smoothly), Is it dangerous for any reason?
3. Where can I find some literature about the "backstage" operations of the sync system call in unix systems (specifically linux)

thanks a lot.